# what is the difference between "Basic Java" and " Core Java"?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between java and core java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000349/what-is-the-difference-between-java-and-core-java)

please somebody help me with this question.
thanks.

Comment: Exact dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000349/what-is-the-difference-between-java-and-core-java

Answer (score 5):

Where have you read these terms? I've never heard about "basic Java" and I actually don't think either of them have a well known / defined / established meaning.

The *Core Java Technologies* are according to Oracle:

> *The Core Java technologies and application programming interfaces (APIs) are the foundation of the Java Platform, Standard Edition (Java SE). They are used in all classes of Java programming, from desktop applications to Java EE applications.*

Comment: The OP is possibly a student down _here_ . There are java programming courses listed like this at most _"computer institutes"_ And students have no idea what they are but go ahead and join anyway.